# How to execute High Volume load test from Performance center

Tags: performance, load-testing, loadrunner, microfocus, hp-performance-center

Can someone please suggest how can we create 'Test Run' in Microfocus performance center 2020 version for below requirement:

At first 100% of VUsers will be loaded into system, after 30 minutes of settling time, overall user load will be increased by 10% and then the test will continue for another 30 mins at 110% user load then again overall user load will be increased by another 10% and the continue for another 30 mins at 120% user load.. this cycle will repeat until the user load reaches 200% then rampdown starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See scheduling for groups of users.  Covered in training material and product documentation